# Interpolation of dates

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a question about interpolation. The case: I have a matrix of 11x2. The first column contains the dates from 2007 up until 2017. The second contains yearly data of the pretax ratio. I want to convert this yearly data into daily data points (n=2609) using the interpolation technique.

I tried using the approx code but I only get errors. Is there someone that has experience with interpolation in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You probably need something like this: `seq(first_date, second_date, "day")`